Solve pyomo.common.errors.InfeasibleConstraintException
After running the below code:
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()

model.q11, model.q12, model.q13, model.q21, model.q22, model.q23, model.q31, model.q32, model.q33 = [Var(bounds=(0.0, 11.0), within=Integers, initialize=0.0) for i in range(9)]
model.s1, model.s2, model.s3 = [Var(bounds=(0.0, 1.0), within=Binary, initialize=0.0) for i in range(3)]
model.S1, model.S2, model.S3 = [Var(bounds=(0.0, 100.0), within=Integers, initialize=0.0) for i in range(3)]

model.c1 = Constraint(expr=model.q11*model.s1*model.S1 + model.q12*model.s1*model.S1 + model.q13*model.s1*model.S1 >= 130.0 - 3.0)
model.c2 = Constraint(expr=model.q11*model.s1*model.S1 + model.q12*model.s1*model.S1 + model.q13*model.s1*model.S1 <= 130.0 + 3.0)

model.c3 = Constraint(expr=model.q21*model.s2*model.S2 + model.q22*model.s2*model.S2 + model.q23*model.s2*model.S2 >= 130.0 - 3.0)
model.c4 = Constraint(expr=model.q21*model.s2*model.S2 + model.q22*model.s2*model.S2 + model.q23*model.s2*model.S2 <= 130.0 + 3.0)

model.c5 = Constraint(expr=model.q31*model.s3*model.S3 + model.q32*model.s3*model.S3 + model.q33*model.s3*model.S3 >= 130.0 - 3.0)
model.c6 = Constraint(expr=model.q31*model.s3*model.S3 + model.q32*model.s3*model.S3 + model.q33*model.s3*model.S3 <= 130.0 + 3.0)

model.c7 = Constraint(expr=model.q11 + model.q12 + model.q13 <= 11.0)
model.c8 = Constraint(expr=model.q21 + model.q22 + model.q23 <= 11.0)
model.c9 = Constraint(expr=model.q31 + model.q32 + model.q33 <= 11.0)

model.objective = Objective(expr=model.s1 + model.s2 + model.s3, sense=minimize)

SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model, mip_solver='glpk', nlp_solver='ipopt') 

model.objective.display()
model.display()
model.pprint()

I get:
    Trivial constraint c1 violates LB 127.0 ≤ BODY 0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/francopiccolo/Git/GitHub/data-in-action/clothes-production-optimization/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyomo/contrib/mindtpy/algorithm_base_class.py", line 1097, in solve_subproblem
    TransformationFactory('contrib.deactivate_trivial_constraints').apply_to(
  File "/Users/francopiccolo/Git/GitHub/data-in-action/clothes-production-optimization/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/transformation.py", line 77, in apply_to
    reverse_token = self._apply_to(model, **kwds)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/francopiccolo/Git/GitHub/data-in-action/clothes-production-optimization/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyomo/contrib/preprocessing/plugins/deactivate_trivial_constraints.py", line 118, in _apply_to
    raise InfeasibleConstraintException(
pyomo.common.errors.InfeasibleConstraintException: Trivial constraint c1 violates LB 127.0 ≤ BODY 0.
Infeasibility detected in deactivate_trivial_constraints.
WARNING: Deactivating trivial constraints on the block unknown for which
trivial constraints were previously deactivated. Reversion will affect all
deactivated constraints.

Any ideas what is going on here and how to overcome this error?

this sets up and solves fine for me.  Are you using latest version (6.7?) of pyomo?

@AirSquid yes 6.7.2, Python 3.12.

Try this small edit (removing mindpy).  This works for me and the only edit is that I altered the solver factory statement because I don't use mindpy and added a printout of the result (which you should always do in some form/fashion):
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()

model.q11, model.q12, model.q13, model.q21, model.q22, model.q23, model.q31, model.q32, model.q33 = [Var(bounds=(0.0, 11.0), within=Integers, initialize=0.0) for i in range(9)]
model.s1, model.s2, model.s3 = [Var(bounds=(0.0, 1.0), within=Binary, initialize=0.0) for i in range(3)]
model.S1, model.S2, model.S3 = [Var(bounds=(0.0, 100.0), within=Integers, initialize=0.0) for i in range(3)]

model.c1 = Constraint(expr=model.q11*model.s1*model.S1 + model.q12*model.s1*model.S1 + model.q13*model.s1*model.S1 >= 130.0 - 3.0)
model.c2 = Constraint(expr=model.q11*model.s1*model.S1 + model.q12*model.s1*model.S1 + model.q13*model.s1*model.S1 <= 130.0 + 3.0)

model.c3 = Constraint(expr=model.q21*model.s2*model.S2 + model.q22*model.s2*model.S2 + model.q23*model.s2*model.S2 >= 130.0 - 3.0)
model.c4 = Constraint(expr=model.q21*model.s2*model.S2 + model.q22*model.s2*model.S2 + model.q23*model.s2*model.S2 <= 130.0 + 3.0)

model.c5 = Constraint(expr=model.q31*model.s3*model.S3 + model.q32*model.s3*model.S3 + model.q33*model.s3*model.S3 >= 130.0 - 3.0)
model.c6 = Constraint(expr=model.q31*model.s3*model.S3 + model.q32*model.s3*model.S3 + model.q33*model.s3*model.S3 <= 130.0 + 3.0)

model.c7 = Constraint(expr=model.q11 + model.q12 + model.q13 <= 11.0)
model.c8 = Constraint(expr=model.q21 + model.q22 + model.q23 <= 11.0)
model.c9 = Constraint(expr=model.q31 + model.q32 + model.q33 <= 11.0)

model.objective = Objective(expr=model.s1 + model.s2 + model.s3, sense=minimize)

solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
result = solver.solve(model) 

print(result)
model.objective.display()
model.display()
model.pprint()


This runs but it doesnt consider the integer nature of the problem, it transforms all the variables into continuous.

Oops.  Yes, of course you are correct.  ipopt only handles continuous vars...  I was suspicious of the model syntax, but I think this proves it to be OK, but doesn't answer your question.  I tried restoring the proper MINLP solver setup you have and I get the same error.  I suspected the problem might be integer-infeasible, so I commented out all but first 2 constraints (which I can see should have a valid solution) and I get the same error.  So I'm stumped...

Buu :(, thanks for trying though.
